# Truffle ganache blockchain loading issue

Tags: flutter, blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I have been developing a flutter/blockchain application and I ran ganache this morning for the first time and it started fine, quick start sent me to the address page everything was good. But when I ran it again hours after that, all it showed the settings page, saved, restarted, reinstalled, nothing works. Anyone knows a solution? Thank you.

Here's the page it's stuck on:

[image: The page it's stuck on]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by researching "ganache" in my C: disk and deleting all the results (temp files , data , everything) and reinstalling again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (+ an extended issue where all I would see is a blank white screen when loading an existing workspace) on Windows 10 and solved it by doing the following:

1. Uninstall Ganache UI
2. Navigate to Roaming and delete the Ganache folder.

   - Search for '%appdata%' in search bar or Run interface through WIN+R
3. Reinstall Ganache UI